# Why toastr notifications not working with my asp.net core 2.0 angular2 application

Tags: .net, angular, asp.net-core, angular2-template

To Install toastr-ng2 in project follow bellow command:

```
npm install toastr-ng2 --save
```

In **ClientApp** vehicle-form.component.ts file add bellow syntax

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

// third party module to display toast 
import { ToastrModule } from 'toastr-ng2';

import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component';
import { NavMenuComponent } from './components/navmenu/navmenu.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { FetchDataComponent } from './components/fetchdata/fetchdata.component';
import { CounterComponent } from './components/counter/counter.component';
import { VehicleFormComponent } from './components/vehicle-form/vehicle-form.component';



@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        NavMenuComponent,
        CounterComponent,
        FetchDataComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        VehicleFormComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        HttpModule,
        FormsModule, 

        ToastrModule.forRoot(),
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'vehicles/new', component: VehicleFormComponent },
            { path: 'counter', component: CounterComponent },
            { path: 'fetch-data', component: FetchDataComponent },
            { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
        ])
    ],
    providers:[

        ]
})
export class AppModuleShared {
}
```

use toasty any component syntax is bellow

```
constructor(private toastyService: ToastrService) { }    
this.toastyService.success('Data inserted Successfully');
```

Now,not get the notification message? What step i miss to get the notification?

Comment: Did you include the css?

Comment: @ Carsten, no i just run the npm command then start use toastr not include the css, how to include the css for toastr asp.net core 2.0 angular template app?

Comment: @shamim did that sort your issue

Comment: @ Sajeetharan it maybe css missing problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do this,

```
 constructor(
    private toastrService: ToastrService,
    private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef
  ) {
    this.toastrService.viewContainerRef = this.viewContainerRef;
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.toastrService.success('Data inserted Successfully', 'Toastr fun!');
  }
```

Comment: The docs (https://www.npmjs.com/package/toastr-ng2) don't mention viewContainerRef

Comment: i guess you need to pass the container

Comment: Why do you guess? Where is the documentation for it?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the same issue like [Toast notification not working in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49623993/toast-notification-not-working-in-angular)

The following goes into the same direction like Carsten say.

When I was working through the same [course from Mosh Hamedani on Udemy](https://www.udemy.com/course/aspnet-core-angular/)

I could solve this isse with the following steps:

1. download the CSS file from https://github.com/akserg/ng2-toasty either bootstrap, default, or material
2. place it under `vega/ClientApp/src/toasty-style-bootstrap.css` in case you went for Bootstrap theming
3. make sure your `vega/ClientApp/angular.json` contains the new style file in the respective section

```
"styles": [
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
      "src/styles.css",
      "src/toasty-style-bootstrap.css"
],
```